# Execute sql from Excel to Access with linked tables from Sharepoint lists

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, sharepoint, ado

I have an Excel file that executes SQL queries on an MS Access database with local tables, works fine. Now I have to get this database to work on a network, we just have SharePoint. I discovered the SharePoint lists, so I exported my tables to these lists and now I have an Access database with linked tables.

Problem is that I can't manage to use my queries from Excel on this database like I use to do. Is it possible? Because I can do these queries from Access and it works, so I don't understand why it wouldn't from Excel. Here is my function:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & "C:\...\BADO.accdb"

    strSql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Programmes;"
    cn.Open strConnection

    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
    MsgBox rs.Fields(0) & " tuples dans Programmes"

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The part of the connection `cn.Open` works, but then when it tries to execute `cn.Execute`, Excel goes into an endless loading and crashes. This code works only with local tables.

If it's not possible, I was thinking that I could let the database with its local tables on SharePoint and let users sync it with OneDrive, but I don't know how the sync works. If the database is heavy, I don't want them to upload every time the full size. So, is there a way to make this code to work?

Comment: Please describe your environment. Is Excel file and/or Access database situated on SharePoint, off SP but a hard-wired LAN, or on local CPU that connects to SP via wireless/remote connection?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this is a networking environment issue. Testing your code from Excel where both the workbook and Access database resides on a network that connects to SharePoint via a Local Area Network (LAN), I experienced no issue of hanging or crashing.

However, running both workbook and Access database from a local CPU that connects to SharePoint via wireless or remote connection, I did experience severe hanging and crashing.

Therefore, consider following options in order of complexity:

1. **LAN Connection**: Situate Excel workbook and Access database on a network space that makes a LAN connection to SharePoint. This may involve users remotely connecting via VPN to a computer on premise.
2. **Action Queries**: Have MS Access run make-table queries from linked to local tables of your simple count aggregations:

   ```sql
   SELECT Count(*) AS [Count] INTO Programmes_Count FROM Programmes;
   ```

   Alternatively, using append queries on a table created in advance which may be better than `DROP TABLE` and re-create each time:

   ```sql
   DELETE FROM Programmes_Count;

   INSERT INTO Programmes_Count ([Count])
   SELECT Count(*) FROM Programmes;
   ```

   Such action queries can be saved and then automated with [Access macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-macros-a39c2a26-e745-4957-8d06-89e0b435aac3) or [modules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/database-basics-a849ac16-07c7-4a31-9948-3c8c94a7c204#__toc257378517) called from Excel. Then have Excel access those local tables.
3. **COM Automation**: Have Excel launch [Access.Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application) as a COM object and then have the database itself query the linked table.

   ```vb
   Sub RunQuery()
       Dim accApp, db, qdef, rst As Object
       Dim strSQL As String

       Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")          ' LAUNCH ACCESS IN BACKGROUND
       accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Path\To\Database.accdb"

       strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) AS [Count] FROM Programmes;"
       Set db = accApp.CurrentDb()                              ' ASSIGN UNDERLYING DB 
       Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)                 ' CREATE QDEF OR USE SAVED
       Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()                           ' OPEN RECORDSET 

       ' LAUNCH MESSAGE BOX 
       MsgBox rst.Fields(0) & " tuples dans Programmes"

       ' CLOSE OBJECTS
       rst.Close: qdef.Close
       accApp.DoCmd.CloseDatabase   
       accApp.Quit

       ' RELEASE RESOURCES
       Set rst = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing: 
       Set db = Nothing: Set accApp = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```

   Even better bypass Access application and query Access via DAO:

   ```vb
   Sub RunQuery()
       Dim conn, db, qdef, rst As Object
       Dim strSQL As String

       Set conn = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")              ' LAUNCH DAO CONNECTION
       Set db = conn.OpenDatabase("C:\Path\To\Database.accdb")

       strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) AS [Count] FROM Programmes;"

       Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)                 ' CREATE QDEF OR USE SAVED    
       Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset()                           ' OPEN RECORDSET

       ' LAUNCH MESSAGE BOX
       MsgBox rst.Fields(0) & " tuples dans Programmes"

       ' CLOSE OBJECTS
       rst.Close: db.Close    

       ' RELEASE RESOURCES    
       Set rst = Nothing: Set qdef = Nothing
       Set db = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: "Ultimately, this is a networking environment issue." Exactly. When I created the linked database, I was in a local area of my computer, and it worked fine. I assumed that if I use the Excel document next to it, it would work, but no. So, thanks to your post, I moved them in the OneDrive area, and then it started to work, no more crashing. Thank you very much ! And you suggested that I bypass Access application and query Access via DAO, so I'll look into it.

Comment: Hmmm....did you test the same query in MS Access? If in local area of your CPU, it should run just as slow as Excel. Remember too a remote connection can have intermittent performance. Works great or hangs every now and then unlike LAN.